# Has Anyone Migrated Away From FinancialForce to Alternate Billing System

Tags: migration, financialforce

We are going to be removing Financial Force from our systems and migrating to an alternate billing system and accounting system (separate). Does anyone here have experience with this, and can you outline some of the gotchas.

Our IS Manager wants to test the new billing system candidates on sandbox environments that have Financial Force still enabled. I can't help but think that is a bad idea. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Hi, any rationale for moving away from Financial Force? Thanks

Comment: Because we want to.